# Unable to add product to cart with some characters in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, cart

I have a weird problem with CI cart. I am unable to add products to cart which contain characters like `(`, `)` and `/`. I'm using version 2.1.4.

Here is my code in the controller:

```
public function add_to_cart() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $product = $this->product_model->get_product($id);

    $item['id']=$product->id;
    $item['name']= $product->name;
    $item['price']=$product->price;
    $item['qty']=1;

    $this->cart->insert($item);

    redirect('cart/view_cart');

}
```

And the model

```
public function get_product($id) {
    return $this->db->get_where('products',array('id'=>$id))->row();
}
```

It works fine unless the product name contain those characters I mentioned above. Anybody experience something like this and know the solution? Please share. Thank you.

Comment: finally  I got the solution [here](http://darrenonthe.net/2011/05/03/cant-add-products-to-codeigniter-shop-cart-class/)

Answer (score 0):

if it's an encoding problem, you can solve this problem by raw

```
    $str = "hi (hello) / merhaba";
    $addCart = rawurlencode($str);
    $decodeCart = rawurldecode($str);

    echo $str . '<br />' .  $addCart . '<br />' .  $decodeCart;
```

add products to cart with encode, then when you need, you can decode.